# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DiagnosticsLogger`1'

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I m trying to migrate my data base using EF core when i run this commande  "dotnet ef migrations add Init --context PersistedGrantDbContext -o Migrations/PersistedGrantDb"
an error has apeared

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have some AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI package installed on your projects. If yes, you need to update them to version 6.0.X.